# Why downcasting is not allowed in C#?

Tags: c#, downcast

i've 2 classes called `EventDto` and `EventWithObjectsDto`. `EventDto` is the parent class and `EventWithObjectsDto` inherits from it.
These are the classes:

```
public class EventDto : BaseDto
{
    public EventTypes Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndAt { get; set; }
    public Guid? RecursiveCriteriaId { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class EventWithObjectsDto : EventDto
{
    public List<ObjectDto> Objects { get; set; }
}
```

I want to cast `EventDto` to `EventWithObjectsDto`, so i've tryed 2 ways:
`var eventWithObjects = (EventWithObjectsDto)ev;` that throws `InvalidCastException` and `var eventWithObjects = ev as EventWithObjectsDto` that returns `null`.
The only way that works is to remove `: EventDto` from `EventWithObjectsDto` and use AutoMapper to map `EventDto` to `EventWithObjectsDto` but i don't want to use AutoMapper is exists another way.

Also, i've done a simple test:

```
var simpleEvent = new EventDto();

// Thrown InvalidCastException
var simpleEventWithObjects = (EventWithObjectsDto)simpleEvent;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't cast something that *isn't* of the target type. We don't know what's creating the object that you're trying to cast, which makes it very hard to help. If you've got some code somewhere using `var dto = new EventDto();` then no, you won't be able to cast that to `EventWithObjectsDto`. You need to find out what's creating the instance.

Comment: @JonSkeet please, see my updated question

Comment: Right, so it's behaving exactly as expected - you're creating something that *isn't* an `EventWithObjectsDto` and trying to cast it to a `EventWithObjectsDto`. That's simply not going to work. Without more context about what you're trying to achieve and why - for example, why you're not creating an `EventWithObjectsDto` to start with - we're not going to be able to help you any further. This is C# working exactly as designed.

Comment: its like, trying to be a parent of your parent which is not possible

Answer (score 2):

The *object* being cast must be of *type* `EventWithObjectsDto` (or derived type).

Here is a little snipped to demonstrate that if it was the cast would be a successful *Event*.

```
var a = new EventWithObjectsDto {Type = "Tip"};
EventDto b = a;
var c = (EventWithObjectsDto) b;
Console.WriteLine(c.Type);
```

Output is:

```
Tip
```

---

## Making an `EventWithObjectsDto` from `EventDto`.

While you cannot cast an object of class `EventDto` to `EventWithObjectsDto`, you can always create an object of derived type from an object of the parent type.

```
class EventWithObjectsDto {
    ...
    public EventWithObjectsDto(EventDto e ){(...)}
}


(...)

var simpleEvent = new EventDto();
var simpleEventWithObjects = new EventWithObjectsDto(simpleEvent);
```

---

Here is a note form [ECMA-334 5th Edition / December 2017C# Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf) that is relevant.

> Reference conversions, implicit or explicit, never change the referential identity of the object being converted. [*Note*:In other words, while a reference conversion can change the type of the reference, it never changes the type or value of the object being referred to. *end note*]

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast `EventDto` to `EventWithObjectsDto`.

Because in OOP theory, `EventDto` is a **generalized** type and `EventWithObjectsDto` is a **specialized** type.

You can cast `EventWithObjectsDto` to `EventDto` because `EventWithObjectsDto` is *larger* than `EventDto`: it includes all `EventDto` operations and variables.

You can't cast `EventDto` to `EventWithObjectsDto` because `EventDto` is *smaller* than `EventWithObjectsDto`: it does not includes all `EventWithObjectsDto` operations and variables.

It is like you want to say when a cat is an animal that all animals are cats: you can't, it is false. Cats are animals but all animals are not cats.

So you have a type mismatch.

[Generalization, Specialization, and Inheritance](https://sourcemaking.com/uml/modeling-it-systems/structural-view/generalization-specialization-and-inheritance)

[Generalization and Specialization - What is the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084034/generalization-and-specialization-what-is-the-differences)

[Upcasting and downcasting in C#](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/oop-csharp/html/notes/inheritance-note-up-down-casting.html)

[What is polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used/58197730#58197730)

All you can do is to use a pattern that copies what have an instance of a child class in an instance of a parent class by checking what variables are common (name and type).